# Ajax success updates markers and infoWindows

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I've been around the block on this over the past week and just haven't found a working solution.  I know I'm missing something simple and believe it is that I need to loop through each existing marker to remove them before posting the new data set.

**GOAL:**
Load an initial set of markers and infoWindows on page load.  Update markers and infoWindows on new data retrieved via ajax and set new bounds.

The initial load is no problem and I'm returning a new set of arrays via ajax with a dataset that has the same formatting as the initial map markers and infoWindows.  My thought was to use the same function for the initial map load and then simply pass the new data arrays to that same function to update the map.  Data passes, but I'm not able to remove or update the data yet.

In theory, is this an acceptable way to tackle this?  If so, how would I go about removing the existing markers and placing the updated markers from 'newMarkers' and 'newInfoWindowContent'.

If there is a better way to be doing this, please...I'm all ears!  I started to create a fiddle, but wanted to first get feedback about the procedure as I feel it is bloated and can be simplified.

Thank you to all in advance!

= = = = =

```
jQuery(function($) {
  // Asynchronously Load the map API 
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAqb3fT3SbMSDMggMEK7fJOIkvamccLrjA&callback=initialize";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
});

function applyFilterMap (cabins) {

  // Loop through old markers and set map to null for each.
  // This is not working.
  setMapOnAll(null); 

  markers = []
  //console.log(markers)


  // Build the array of new markers from filtered results.
  newMarkers = '';
  newMarkers += '[';
  $.each(cabins, function(i, cabin) {
    newMarkers += '[\''+ cabin.name + '\', ' + cabin.latitude + ', ' + cabin.longitude +'],'
  });
  newMarkers = newMarkers.slice(0, -1);
  newMarkers += ']';

  // Build the array of new infoWindowContent from filtered results.
  newInfoWindowContent = '';
  newInfoWindowContent += '[';
  $.each(cabins, function(i, cabin) {
    newInfoWindowContent += '[\'<div class="property clearfix"><div class="image"><div class="content"><a href="'+ cabin.listing_url + '" onclick="ga(\'send\', \'event\', \'Destination-Listing\', \'Map - Photo\', \'' + cabin.destination + ' - ' + cabin.name + '\', 1);"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a><img src="' + cabin.image_url + '" alt="' + cabin.name + '" class="img-responsive" onload="ga(\'send\', \'event\', \'Impression-MapPin\', \'' + cabin.property.destination.slug + '\', \'' + cabin.cabinid + '\', 1);"><span class="label-sleeps"><i class="fa fa-group"></i> ' + cabin.maxguests + '</span> <span class="label-price">$'+ cabin.minrate + '</span></div></div><div class="property-detail"><h5 class="title"><a href="' + cabin.list_url + '" onclick="ga(\'send\', \'event\', \'Destination-Listing\', \'Map - Name\', \'' + cabin.destination + ' - ' + cabin.name + '\', 1);">' + cabin.name + '</a></h5><h5>' + cabin.property.org.name + '</h5></div></div>\'],'
  });
  newInfoWindowContent = newInfoWindowContent.slice(0, -1);
  newInfoWindowContent += ']';

  // console.log(newMarkers);
  // console.log(newInfoWindowContent);  

  initialize(newMarkers, newInfoWindowContent);

  // Display the Map after it has been filtered and updated.
  // $('#destinationMap_wrapper').html('<h3>New Map Here</h3>');
  $('#sizeMap').fadeIn('fast');
  $('#destinationMap_wrapper').fadeIn('fast');

} // END applyFilterMap() Function.

/// Initialize Map for initial load.
function initialize(newMarkers, newInfoWindowContent) {

var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
};

// Create Markers
if(newMarkers) {
  markers = newMarkers;
} else {
  markers = [
    ['The Encantado', 40.38917970, -105.46607810],
    ['Valhalla', 40.35821830, -105.56307860],
    ['Mountain Side', 40.39301450, -105.43687520],
  ];
}

// Info Window Content
if(newInfoWindowContent) {
  infoWindowContent = newInfoWindowContent;
} else {
  infoWindowContent = [
    ['<h3>The Encantado Info</h3>'],
    ['<h3>Valhalla Info</h3>'],
    ['<h3>Mountain Side Info</h3>']
  ];
}

// Display map on the page
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("destinationMap_canvas"), mapOptions);

// Display markers on map
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

// Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][0]
    });

    // Create info window for each marker    
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
            // map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));

    // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

// Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs.
var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
    google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
});

}

function setMapOnAll(map1) {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(map1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok now how are you updating your markers

Comment: EDIT - I have added the function that is creating the newMarkers and newInfoWindowContent.  That function is fired upon success of an ajax request.  We are basically apply a filter to a set of results and the return is giving us the data to build our new arrays for the listings (and in this case, the map).

Comment: i added a response did you see it

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: setMapOnAll is not defined`

Comment: I just added the setupMapOnAll() function.  I feel that is what I'm missing.  Somewhere I 'think' I need to set the markers on the initial page load so that I can then remove them and then reset them with the new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your `applyFilterMap` you are defining the newMarkers as an string that have the representation of an array (so its not an array) and in your `initilize` method you are waiting for an array to loop. Its the same issue for the newInfoWindowContent. You can try a code like this

```
    newMarkers = [];
  $.each(cabins, function(i, cabin) {
    newMarkers.push([ ''+cabin.name ,  cabin.latitude , cabin.longitude])
  });
```

And apply the same thing for the newInfoWindowContent. but the code will all that div is a real mess try testing with simple text if it works apply your html with some cleaning

**UPDATE**

here is a possible version of your method

```
    function applyFilterMap (cabins) {

  // Loop through old markers and set map to null for each.
  // This is not working.
  //setMapOnAll(null);

  markers = []
  //console.log(markers)


  // Build the array of new markers from filtered results.
  newMarkers = [];
  $.each(cabins, function(i, cabin) {
    newMarkers.push([ ''+cabin.name ,  cabin.latitude , cabin.longitude])
  });

  // Build the array of new infoWindowContent from filtered results.
  newInfoWindowContent = []
  $.each(cabins, function(i, cabin) {
    var oneArray = ['<h3>'+cabin.name+'</h3>'];
    newInfoWindowContent.push(oneArray);
  });

  // console.log(newMarkers);
  // console.log(newInfoWindowContent);

  initialize(newMarkers, newInfoWindowContent);

  // Display the Map after it has been filtered and updated.
  // $('#destinationMap_wrapper').html('<h3>New Map Here</h3>');
  $('#sizeMap').fadeIn('fast');
  $('#destinationMap_wrapper').fadeIn('fast');

}
```

Comment: I will give this a shot tonight after the rugrat goes to bed - in about an hour.  However, I still feel that I need to 'remove' an 're-add' the markers from the original page load to the new ajax data.  From what I had read before, I'm missing something about removing them.  Yet, I'll give this a shot here soon - thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you douxsey!  There are multiple functions at work here, yet you were able to hone right in on the root problem.  I know better than this and should have seen what I was doing in creating those arrays.  Thank you so much!